# How to install ROS in raspberry pi 4 Bullseye

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros can be installed on raspberry pi 4 Bullseye

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413058/how-to-install-ros-in-raspberry-pi-4-bullseye/) by [carlossortiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/141110/carlossortiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2023-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Bullseye is not an officially supported distribution for ROS Noetic as from #q405670

I suggest downgrading your Raspberry Pi OS is a Debian buster.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2023-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0